# Was the complete Guyver manga ever officially released in English?

Tags: guyver

I have long been a fan of the Guyver. I watched the older 12-part OVA as a kid and I just recently watched the later 26-part anime on YouTube. I really enjoyed it and it seems to cover more of the story than the older version, but it is still not complete.

I am wondering if there was ever an official release of an English translation of the complete Guyver manga? I looked into the US VIZ comic book version, but that seems to cover a similar range of the story to the 26-part anime (i.e. about a third of the manga), so it is not complete. I have found what seems to be an English version of the complete manga online, but I'm not sure if it is official or a fan translation (I won't link it, just in case).

Answer (score 2):

According to [ANN](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=2451) and [Anisearch](https://www.anisearch.com/manga/1897,the-bio-booster-armor-guyver): No.

For me it seems that Viz canceled the series back then and lost the license

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is what I had suspected.